# How to dispatcher servlet map the requests?

Tags: spring

I want to know how to DispatcherServlet forward the request to the controller,suppose i do have multiple like controller1 having mapped method for /index.htm and another controller2 also have mapped method for /index.htm and in url if i call index.htm then how it decide that whether to call controller1's index.htm or controller2's or index.htm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two Controller Handler Methods with the same RequestMapping (based on path, method, headers, params etc).

Spring will throw an exception if you do.

What are you trying to accomplish?